# We're being discussed on meta^2. Users may want to contribute

Tags: discussion

Discussion taking place here:
[Beta site degrading in quality, per-site Meta discussion reveals that it's not perceived as a issue; what more can I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243705/beta-site-degrading-in-quality-per-site-meta-discussion-reveals-that-its-not-p)

which site users may want to contribute to.